# Forms Authentication for different roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a website in which I'm using forms authentication.
We have 2 log in pages: one for user, another for admin.

I added this code into webconfig file for user.

```
<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"  defaultUrl="Home.aspx" >
```

I am using this code for user side when user successfully logged in.

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage (UserName.Text, chkPersistCookie.Checked)
```

I am not using the default user membership database. I have my own database in SQL Server 2005.

I want same thing for admin, but the default url is Admin.aspx & login url is adminlogin.aspx for admin.

How can i assign in web config file for admin? Is it the right way to do that or any one have some better concept for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used This line of code and this worked for me.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUser.Text, true);
Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting admin files to a folder and creating a web.config file in it, is an option. You can probably override the config rules there.

Comment: Can you please tell me another option without two config.